# Cannot distribute AdHoc ipa file

Tags: iphone, wireless, adhoc, ipa

I have a xcode project that I would like to distribute to collegues of mine, I have therefore added all my collegues UDID in the devices section of the provisioning portal, I then downloaded the distribute and the Ad hoc provisioning files and clicked on them so that they came in to my organazizer. I then used them in xcode and selected "build-archive", I then followed this guide http://gknops.github.com/adHocGenerate/ to make a wireless app distribution. And uploaded the provisiong file, plist file and the ipa file. But when I try to install the app using the link in my html file it start to install but fail with this message " "Appnamexxxx" could not be installed right now". I dont know what I'm doing wrong and the error I get doesn't tell me anything...

Comment: Please! confirm me, after build archive did you try to install IPA in your device through iTunes etc. still not sure your IPA has problem or after sending over the network you having trouble.

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason why it didn't work. I had entered the UDID of all the devices in the provisioning portal, but I didn't check that they where supposed to be used with that profile. I thought that if I entered UDID they where automatically selected to be used with the profile, this I found out by pure luck when trying to find the reason for this in the portal. So one have to select the provisionig and choose edit, then you have the reason to check/uncheck the UDID's you want in that profile. Hope this can help others too.

Answer (score 0):

Hello there try to use betabuilder.http://www.hanchorllc.com/2010/08/24/introducing-ios-beta-builder/